# modify the column display data of Index method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model class,

```
public class CustomerModel
    {       
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        public int CustomerPoints { get; set; }
        
    }
```

In the controller method

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Customers.ToList());
        }
```

In the `CustomerPoints` column I am getting integer number. I want to display user friendly message for this field.
Like,

```
If CustomerPoints value < 10 then bronze
CustomerPoints value >10 && < 20 silver
CustomerPoints value >20 && < 30 gold
CustomerPoints value >30 && < 40 diamond
```

How can I do this? Please help, I am new to MVC platform. Thank You.

Answer (score -2):

Keep the model class as below,

```
public class CustomerModel
{       
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public int CustomerPoints { get; set; }

    public List<CustomerModel> CustomerList { get; set; }
    
}
```

Keep the Action method as below ,

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
       
       CustomerModel model=new CustomerModel();
           
       model.CustomerList= (from n in db.Customers
                           select new CustomerModel 
                           {
                               CustomerPoints=n.CustomerPoints < 10 ? 
                                               "bronze":n.CustomerPoints >10 && 
                                                 n.CustomerPoints <20 ? "silver"
                           }).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

And will be ,

```
     @model CustomerModel  
   @{  
   
  }  
 <h2></h2>  

 
   <table class="table">  
 <tr>  
    
    <th>Customer Points </th>  
</tr>  

  @foreach (var item in Model.CustomerList ) {  
<tr>  
    <td>  
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerPoints)  
    </td>  
    
</tr>
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can I do the same using ViewModel rather than keeping `public List<CustomerModel> CustomerList { get; set; }` in Model class?

Comment: You have used `terneray operator` in `CustomerPoints` but I have more than 2 conditions, how can I use if else here?

Comment: Your code block `select new CustomerModel ...` has error, please check once. Thank You!!